# QT QPainter error in class derived from QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: qt4

I try to write a small hex editor. For that I want to create a widget that displays the hex data and scrolls by line. For that I started experimenting by deriving from the QAbstractScrollArea and overriding the paintEvent() like this:

```
void CuteHexeEditorWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPoint position(50,50);
    QString text("00 11 22");
    painter.drawText(position, text);
}
```

The code gets called but in the console I see the following message: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The QPainter has to be created on the viewport:

```
QPainter painter(viewport());
```